# How to get the most displaying column value in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this table:

```
Aid id date
--------------
 1   1   19/12
 2   1   20/5
 3   2   30/2
```

I want to get the id that is showing the most so in this case I want to get 1
(SELECT id)...

Should be like this:

```
id
 1
```

I just want to get the max of count id

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT TOP 1 id from 
(SELECT id, COUNT(id) AS freq FROM table1
GROUP BY id) t1
ORDER BY t1.freq desc
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55cd5/6)

Comment: when im tryig it on accsess im getting systax error (missing operator)COUNT(id) freq @snyder

Comment: Access SQL requires you to use `AS` for the field expression alias.  So change `COUNT(id) freq` to `COUNT(id) AS freq`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 ArtistID
FROM AwardToArtis
group by ArtistID
order by ArtistID desc
```

thats solve it for me